# if been trigger by something other than a bool

Tags: javascript, express

ok, I'm fully aware that this is a very simple question, but still is bothering me and i haven't been able to  find the answer

i got this code

```
//the findOne method return the first matched element from my database    
let user = await User.findOne({email});
```

then I got this if that returns an error if the user does not exist

```
if(!user){
            
    return res.status(400).json({ errors: [ {msg: 'Invalid credentials'} ] });
}
```

So why is user triggering the if statement bc to my knowledge an if can only be trigger by a true on the condition and the findOne method is returning an object from the database not a bool telling me that it exists

Comment: The `!user` is a JS way of saying user is null.

Comment: ok but lets say that i don't have the ! that would be an object and for what I have tested is also triggers the if

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT):

> The logical NOT (!) operator (logical complement, negation) takes truth to falsity and vice versa. It is typically used with Boolean (logical) values. When used with non-Boolean values, it returns false if its single operand can be converted to true; otherwise, returns true.

> Returns false if its single operand can be converted to true; otherwise, returns true.
>
> If a value can be converted to true, the value is so-called truthy. If a value can be converted to false, the value is so-called falsy.
>
> Examples of expressions that can be converted to false are:
>
> - null;
> - NaN;
> - 0;
> - empty string ("" or '' or ``);
> - undefined.

An object is none of those things, so is a truthy value, so `!` will convert it to false.

```js
console.log("object", {});
console.log("not object", !{});
console.log("not not object", !!{});
console.log("one", 1);
console.log("not one", !1);
console.log("zero", 0);
console.log("not zero", !0);
```

Comment: ok so the object itself can be taken as a truthy value, that's the answer to my question